# AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner throwing RuntimeException Android

Tags: android, junit4, handler, android-junit, androidjunitrunner

I am developing an Android app. I am writing the Junit test for the android and I am a novice in the Junit test case.

In-app I have one relative layout on click of that I am opening date picker dialog box and once the user selects the date I am showing in the TextView.

I want to test these actions with Junit. When I try to run the test case it is throwing me following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:205)
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:118)
at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:123)
at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:201)
at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:197)
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:115)
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:90)
at com.example.sride.DataSelectedTest.loginClickedSuccess(DataSelectedTest.java:74)
```

Here is my Test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class DataSelectedTest {

    private Context appContext;

    @Test
    public void useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        appContext = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
        assertEquals("com.example.sride", appContext.getPackageName());
    }

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void datCheckSuccess() throws Throwable {
        Log.e("@Test", "Performing date check success test");
        Espresso.onView((withId(R.id.calendarRl)))
                .perform(ViewActions.click());

        // throwing error at this line
        // If I remove this line then it is working as expected
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog =
                new DatePickerDialog(mActivityRule.getActivity(), null, 2012, 6, 7);

        datePickerDialog.dismiss();

        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.dateTv))
                .check(matches(withText("7" + "-" + (6 + 1) + "-" + "2012")));
    }
}
```

I also tried these codes to run inside `runOnUiTHeard()` but the problem still persists.

I also tried these codes to run inside `Handler()` but the test will keep on running not showing any output

Am I missing something?

Comment: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900022/3290339) is old, but might be helpful.

Comment: @Onik I tried this but it is going infinite

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link which may solve your problem. To work on real instance of your activity, you would need either an instrumentation test or you may need to use Roboelectric.

[Instrumented Unit Class Test - Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458735/instrumented-unit-class-test-cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-c)